# Programmatically find Partition Key Path of Cosmos Container

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

```
var cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(EndpointUrl, AuthorizationKey,
    new CosmosClientOptions() {
      AllowBulkExecution = true
    });

var database = cosmosClient.GetDatabase(SourceDatabase);
var container = database.GetContainer(SourceContainerName);
```

> I'm looking for an approach to programmatically find out
> `PartitionKeyPath` for the container. Is there no API in the SDK to
> obtain it from container object?

P.S. Microsoft displays partition key path in Azure portal.
Was wondering how do they display it?

Answer (score 1):

In Azure SDK for .NET, JSON path used for containers partitioning can be found using

```
 ContainerProperties.PartitionKeyPath Property
```

PartitionKeyPath defaults to "/PartitionKey".  Refer: [Ms doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.containerproperties.partitionkeypath?view=azure-dotnet)

```
ContainerProperties cproperties = await container.ReadContainerAsync();             
Console.WriteLine(cproperties.PartitionKeyPath);
```

Additionally, you can go ahead and share this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/users/166622403-azure-cosmos-db-team) so the CosmosDB team can look into this idea.✌

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the partition key of a container you have to use the [`GetContainerQueryIterator()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.database.getcontainerqueryiterator) method. Depending on what is already available within your code, you could use something like this:

```
private static async Task<string> GetPartitionKey(Database database, string containerName)
{
    var query = new QueryDefinition("select * from c where c.id = @id")
        .WithParameter("@id", containerName);
    using var iterator = database.GetContainerQueryIterator<ContainerProperties>(query);

    while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
    {
        foreach (var container in await iterator.ReadNextAsync())
        {
            return container.PartitionKeyPath;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In version 3.31.2 you can access the PartitionKeyPath as follows

```
var containerResponse = await cosmosClient.GetDatabase(options.Value.Database)
                                          .GetContainer(collectionId)
                                          .ReadContainerAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

Console.WriteLine(containerResponse.Resource.PartitionKeyPath)
```